# How to create external API for program?

Tags: c, api

For example, I have a simple program like this:

```
//Program A
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int main(void) {
    doSomeStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

I have started it and it is running. And have program B.
My questions are:

1. How can I connect from my program B to program A and ask it to run, for example, function add?
2. How can I write external API for always running program A?

Or, maybe similar example, think about some database and driver for it. How can driver request a database?

Comment: The more specific your questions, the better we can help.

Comment: Do you want to *call* functions like `add` and `sub` here, in other words create a *library*? Or to you want to have this program running and call the functions as *remote procedure calls* (using whatever RPC protocol)? Or what?

Comment: You should probably think about *how* program A and program B connect.  Are they in the same process?  Same computer?  What protocol are they using to talk?

Comment: I don't want to create a library. They are running at the same computer at different processes. For example, program A - database server, program B - driver for database. How they communicate?

Comment: If program B is database then your program A communicates with the DB over DLL driver. I.e. there is library that you don't want... Two processes can communicate directly over TCP, Pipes or Message Queues but then they use standard API from OS (sockets, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create dynamic library. For Windows it is .DLL. In Unix world also exists but I am not expert there. The DLL exports some functions (API). When your EXE file uses some of them, the DLL is loaded by OS at runtime and necessary functions are "connected" (i.e. function calls in EXE are redirected to entry points of loaded DLL). You can find example of DLL, e.g. in Codeproject.com.